# Error accessing GStreamer Library in Qt C++ - Program excited with code 0xc0000135 when Debugging

Tags: c++, windows, qt, debugging, gstreamer

I want to use gstreamer library for video programming and I read that Qt5.5.0 provided support for gstreamer-1.0, which is the library I use. I downloaded firstly version 1.0.7, but I got the following error, so I downloaded the latest version 1.5.2, which I am trying to use now.

I managed to link the gstreamer library header files, so I didn't build it, but just include its path and access the header files and libs. Anyway, now I have an error of The program has unexpectedly finished. When I try to debug it, I get the following error in a pop-up:
**During startup program excited with code 0xc0000135**.

On General Messages:

*:1:24: Reading only version 1.1 parts.
:10:5: Expected only Component and ModuleApi object definitions.*

I read many questions related to this error, but none helped, I think is an error with the gstreamer library, but may be a compiler/debugger error too, as I read in some threads.

I checked my PATH variable, as I also can not run the program outside Qt (by trying to run the .exe in debug folder of the build) - the error : library Qt5Cored.dll missing - and I found this paths:

C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0_Android\5.5\mingw492_32\lib;
C:\Users\user\Documents\build-GStreamer-test5-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug;
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0_Android\5.5\mingw492_32\bin;
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0_Android\Tools\mingw492_32\bin;
C:\Windows\system32; C:\Windows; C:\Windows\System32\Wbem; C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\ (I dont know why is this included, but it was there when I checked )

I am relatively new to Qt, and never encountered this error before. If you need any code:

.pro:

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = GStreamer-test5
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += mainwindow.h

FORMS += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0
C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include
C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0
C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include

LIBS += -L C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/ -lgstreamer-1.0
```

and .main:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <QDebug>

#include <stdio.h>
#include "gst/gst.h"

void *__gxx_personality_v0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

const gchar *nano_str;
guint major, minor, micro, nano;

gst_init (&argc, &argv);

gst_version (&major, &minor, &micro, &nano);

if (nano == 1)
nano_str = "(CVS)";
else if (nano == 2)
nano_str = "(Prerelease)";
else
nano_str = "";

// printf ("This program is linked against GStreamer %d.%d.%d %s\n", major, minor, micro, nano_str);

qDebug() << "This program is linked against GStreamer %d.%d.%d %s\n", major, minor, micro, nano_str ;

return a.exec();
```

Firstly, I had the error :
**undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'** , but fixed it by adding ***void __gxx_personality_v0;** , although I don't know what excatly it is.

Its been three days I struggle with this problem. Any help appreciated, or maybe if you can help me by some code on how to access the header files and libs, or how the configuration of the debugger options / PATH must be.

I am using Qt5.5.0 for Android, for Windows I use **MinGW 4.9.2 32 bit** compiler and **GNU gdb 7.8** as debugger.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding `void *__gxx_personality_v0;` is like putting a band-aid on a broken leg - you still fall over when trying to walk. That symbol is part of the compiler's standard library, which you **have** to link against. Otherwise it will almost certainly crash during start-up.

Comment: So what should I do in this case, I mean can the broken leg be fixed, or I should continue with the band-aid? :)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems in my project that was using both Qt and Gstreamer.

The сause of "undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'" error is that Qt and GStreamer for windows from official sites were built using different compilers and their libstdc++ libraries are not compatible - they are using different exception handling methods.
In fact, GStreamer is pure C library. The only component of it that was written in C++ is taglib library. If you will build this lib from sources using your MinGW compiler, and then replace it in the GStreamer folder, the problem of incompatibility will be solved.
In more detail you can read here: https://github.com/knowthelist/knowthelist.

Comment: Back from the future, you saved me many linker errors!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the above problem. I had to include in the .exe folder (the build-debug folder) all the dlls included, so I tried to run the .exe from there, not run it from Qt, and some errors with dlls missing gave me the names of the dlls. I found some in my library bin folder and some downloaded, and now everything seems fine :)